# How to order by date in laravel 5 SQL Query?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to select the date value and count the number of it's appearance order by the date. this is my SQL Query code:

```
$b = DB::table('entry')
                        ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') as tanggal"))
                        ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y')"))
                        ->orderBy(DB::raw("CONVERT(DateTime, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y'), 101)"))
                        ->get();
```

What's wrong with that query?, help me guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have way to many parenthesis of subgroupings.  For the last line, get(); I don't see how any program would know what value inside parenthesis you are trying to get as there are a total of 9 items within parenthesis in your 3 lines.